# AttributeError: type object 'Questiontwo' has no attribute 'question2'

Tags: python, forms, django-forms

I am currently starting Django and trying to build a questionnaire app for scoring risk tolerance.
tried to build with the wizard form technique. However, there is an error raised AttributeError: The type object "Questiontwo" has no attribute "question2."

solving this error should outputting the score number in the httpresponse page

model.py:

```
class User (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models. CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name, self.last_name)

class Risk_Profile(models.Model):
    score_risk_toler= models.PositiveIntegerField()
    score_risk_capc= models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_score=models.IntegerField()
    dude = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import *
class Signup(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    
    class Meta:
        model= User 
        fields =('name','last_name','phone','email')



class Questionone (forms.Form):
    # Risk Capcity 
    choice = ((25, "build long term wealth."), (20, "prepare for retirement"), (20, "save for something special (vacation, new car, etc.)"), (10, "save for major upcoming expenses (education, health bills, etc.)."),
    (0,"build a rainy day fund for emergencies"),(0,"generate income for expenses."))
   
    question1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label="What is your goal for this account?")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.question1)

class Questiontwo (forms.Form):
    # Risk TOLERANCE
    choice = ((0, "No."), (7, "Some"), (11, "Good"),
        (15,"Extensive"))

    question2= forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, label="What is your understanding of stocks, bonds, and ETFs?") 

    Risk_Profile.score_risk_toler=question2


class Questionthree (forms.Form):
        # Risk Tolerance
    choice = ((0, "I worry I could be left with nothing."), (3, "I understand that it is an inherent part of the investing process."), (7, "I see opportunity for great returns."),
    (10,"I think of the thrill of investing."))
    question3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label="When you hear risk related to your finances, what is the first thought that comes to mind?") 
    

class Questionfour (forms.Form):
        # Risk Tolerance
    choice = ((0, "Sold Everthing "), (10, "Sold Some "), (5, "Did Nothing."),
    (20," Relocate My Investment"),(40,"Buy More"))

    question4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label=" What (did or will) you do when you  (will experience or experienced) a 20% decline the value of your investments?") 
        

class Questionfive (forms.Form):
        # Risk Tolerance
    choice = ((0, "I try to avoid making decisions. "), (6, "I reluctantly make decisions "), (15, ". I confidently make decisions and don’t look back."))

    question5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label=" How would you describe your approach to making important financial decisions?") 
        

class Questionsix (forms.Form):
        # Risk Capcity
    choice = ((5, "$5,000 to $25,000 "), (10, " More Than $25,000") )

    question6 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label=" How much do you want to invest to get started?") 
        

class Questionseven (forms.Form):
        # Risk Tolerance
    choice = ((0, "−10% to 15%"), (5, "−15% to 25%"), (8, "−25% to 35%"),
        (10," −30% to 45%"),(13,"−35% to 50%"),(17 ,". −40% to 55%"),(20,"−45% to 60%"))

    question7 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label=" How much investment value fluctuation would you be comfortable with 1 year from now?") 
        

class Questioneight (forms.Form):
        # Risk CAPCITY
    choice = ((5, "Monthly Contribution / Initial Investment < 10%"), (5, "Monthly Contribution / Initial Investment ≥ 10%"))

    question8 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label=" How much do you want to contribute each month?")
        

class Questionnine (forms.Form):
        # Risk CAPCITY
    def __init__(self,question9 ):
        self.question9= question9 
    choice = ((0, "1 to 4 years"), (5, ". 5 to 9 years"),(20,"10 to 19 years"),(35,"Over 19 years"))
    question9 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices= choice, coerce=int, widget= forms.RadioSelect, label="How much do you want to contribute each month?")
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from .forms import Signup, Questionone, Questiontwo, Questionthree, Questionfour, Questionfive, Questionsix, Questionseven,Questioneight,Questionnine 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import
```

views.py:

```
class FormWizardView(SessionWizardView):

    form_list = [Signup, Questiontwo]
    template_name='index.html'

    def done(self,form_list, **kwarg):
            scorecap= Questiontwo.question2
            Risk_Profile.score_risk_capc= int(scorecap)
            return HttpResponse("submitted")
```